# Deployment of standalone jar (Heroku) - Exceptions

Tags: heroku, jakarta-ee, jar, war

I am trying to deploy executable war (java -jar myapp.jar) on *Heroku*, which I am successfully able to execute on local machine.

I followed below steps to do it on heroku using CLI

1. heroku plugins:install java
2. heroku create --no-remote --app testjar
3. heroku deploy:jar target/my-app.jar --app testjar

First two steps run fine... but in 3rd I got below exception. Any idea on the cause ?  Or what information it wants? I Have given it all as per the document https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files

> Uploading funApp.jar
>      events.js:167
>      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>      ^
>   Error: spawn java ENOENT
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
>      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
>      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
>      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
>      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
>   docker@default:/c/Users/Abhi/DockerAppHub/heroku/bin$ ./heroku deploy:jar ./funApp.jar --app testjar08
>   Uploading funApp.jar events.js:167
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>   Error: spawn java ENOENT
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
>      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
>      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:252:12)
>      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:421:16)
>      at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)

Comment: I was able to achieve the deployment through docker container. So we may close this issue. Even if the jar would have been deployed, there was no way that heroku could map a port to it. So if above issue is not happening frequently or is reported first time, it can be put under monitored or  closed as of now...Thanks

Comment: I was able to achieve the deployment through docker container. So we may close this issue. Even if the jar would have been deployed, there was no way that heroku could map a port to it. So if above issue is not happening frequently or is reported first time, it can be put under monitored or  closed as of now...Thanks